# Looping exceed the array limit

Tags: php, loops

Using PHP as example , there is an array:

```
$list = array("a", "b", "c");
```

I would like to get the Nth element of the array as if it were an infinite loop. For example, the 11th element here would be `"b"`:

```
 a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c ...
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ...
                               ^
```

How to loop on the array to get this?

Comment: `echo $list[10];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use `%` modulus

```
<?php

$list = array("a", "b", "c");
$position = 11;
$index = $position % count($list) - 1;

echo $list[$index];
```

demo : https://eval.in/847933

Answer (score 1):

Use this one for whatever position you want to print with abcabc.....

```
<?php
$list = array("a", "b", "c");
$position = 11;
$ListAdd = [];
$listArr = [];

$ListAdd = str_split(str_repeat(implode('', $list),(($position/count($list))+1)));

for ($j = 0; $j< $position; $j++){
  $listArr[] = $ListAdd[$j]; 
}

foreach($listArr as $value){
echo  $value;  
}
?>
```

I think it'll help for you.